# Java/Kotlin - Concurrent Linked Queue of a specific size

Tags: java, kotlin, thread-safety

I have a use-case where I am processing locations to use for event validation. This is a multi-threaded environment, so I'd like to use a thread safe queue data structure of some sort.

`ConcurrentLinkedQueue` does almost exactly what I want, but there is no way to specific the max size of the queue. I'd like to only be able to fit N elements in the queue, and then throw the "oldest" one away (FIFO for example) if adding an element would exceed the size of the queue.

`LinkedBlockingQueue` seems similar to what I want, but I DO NOT want the blocking behavior when the queue is full - I just want the oldest value to be evicted and the new value inserted.

Is there a default implementation of this that I could leverage? Or would it involve a custom implementation of a doubly linked list for example?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a default implementation of this that I could leverage?

To the best of my knowledge, there is no queue implementation in the standard library that discards enqueued objects without them having been explicitly removed.  I would be inclined to interpret that as contrary to the general contract of the `java.util.Queue` interface, in fact.  An object enqueued on a `Queue` should remain there until dequeued.

That does not mean you can't roll your own, even as an implementation of `Queue`.  But I doubt that you could do it in a manner that is both thread safe and lock-free.

> Or would it involve a custom implementation of a doubly linked list for example?

Your implementation options are pretty wide open.  Among them are variations on wrapping or extending existing `Queue` or `List` implementations.  I do not see what would be gained by implementing a linked list from scratch.

Comment: Is there an implementation that is thread safe where I could check the size of the list before inserting and delete the "first" item if I need to? Seems like a `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` might be an option here? I'm only going to have 10-20 items in the queue at any point in time, so the call to size() shouldn't be too expensive (and I'll be inserting every second roughly).

Comment: @Citut, There are lots of implementations where the needed operations are *individually* thread safe and maybe even lock-free, but for your purpose you need to perform two or three such operations *together* as a single thread safe unit, and for that you will need to lock.  Which again, you can do.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to venture into the world of Reactive Programming, Project Reactor's [Flux](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#flux) has an [onBackpressureBuffer](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#onBackpressureBuffer-int-reactor.core.publisher.BufferOverflowStrategy-) method that takes a size limit and an overflow strategy. [`BufferOverflowStrategy.DROP_OLDEST`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/BufferOverflowStrategy.html#DROP_OLDEST) has the behavior you're asking for.